# JQuery Facebook like Tag feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

Does anyone know of a very basic tag JQuery script? (Facebook like tag feature)

All I want to do is when I type @ in a text box for it to search an AJAX search, it then brings back a display name i.e. "Bob Johnson" and an associated Id and stores the Id in a comma delimited list.

So an example would be the following ....

[TextArea]
[Name 1]
[Name 2]
[Name 3]

The thing is it also needs to remove this entry (Id) once the tag gets removed, also it needs to load into a DIV which has a scrollbar so that the list doesn't get to big.

If anyone know's how/if this is possible that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: I'm pretty much done with [**jQuery UI Tagging**](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/mcWnL/52/). The `source` option works just like jQuery UI Autocomplete's so you can pass a function to it that return an `Array` or just pass an `Array` directly.

Comment: Mmm yes this might work quite well. I am a bit of a JQuery newb I've got to admit ;) I think my main problem is having it load in a DIV that has a scrollbar and showing the relevant ID's. But people must also be able to type normal text, just like a facebook status, if that makes any sense? Thanks for you're help.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I tried to add an AJAX call into you're code but I cant seem to get it working. I added the following under the var matches = []; but ...

Comment: $.ajax({
      url: 'search.asp?SearchTerm=' + searchTerm,
        success: function(data) {
       var names = data;
        }
     });

Comment: Try with the latest version that I've linked to in the answer. I will continue to update this so you can always check the [base](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/mcWnL/) for new versions.

Comment: Looks great Marcus, thanks for you're help. The only issue I see is that it doesn't update the hidden field correctly when you remove one?

Comment: @Tech, exactly. That's the next thing I'm going to fix. Will come back to you when it's done!

Comment: Nice - I am looking forward to this and then all I need to put in is an AJAX call, which "should" in theory be quite easy!

Comment: Hi Marcus, when do you think I could have a look at a final version? I've tried modifying what you provided to fix the hidden field issue and add AJAX but it broke!

Comment: @Tech, I might have the time to finish it off this evening :)

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I am excited! :)

Comment: @Tech, and as promised. It's done! I've updated the link in the answer. Follow me on twitter @mekwall for updates on this since I'm going to release it to the public!

Comment: Marcus - many thanks for you're help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Tech, if you are happy with the result please vote and accept this answer :)

Comment: @Marcus All I need is an AJAX call instead of the Array now, how exactly could I do this?

Comment: @Tech, I'll add that to the demo :) hang tight!

Comment: It's very good, but seem not working in IE8... Other than that - looking stunning

Comment: @Nik Hey! This one is kinda old nowadays, but IE8 is even older. More or less every major player have dropped support for IE8, and so should you :)

Comment: Doesn't appear to be working in firefox for me, but thanks so much for this solution...a great starting point for what i'm trying to accomplish.